# Active Directory LDAP authentication fail if username contains dots (.)

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I made an Active Directory (winserver 2012) LDAP authenticator in Java, and in this case, when the AD username contains dost (.), the authentication fails, with this exception:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0904F8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v23f0
```

If the username doesn't contain dot, the auth. works fine.

There is the code:

```
private DirContext getDirContext(String username, String password) {

    ...

    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "DIGEST-MD5");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://server.test.local:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "test.user");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
    env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectGUID objectSid");

    DirContext ctx;

    try {
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        getLogger().log(Level.WARNING,
                "ACTIVE DIRECTORY - AUTHENTICATION ERROR: " + ex);
    }

    return ctx;
}
```

I tried replace the dot to %2e, and I tried the full username (test.user@test.local), but these didn't solve my problem.

Has anybody any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to add the domain (IE: DOMAIN\\+ user) 
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570222/how-to-authenticate-against-active-directory-via-ldap-over-tls

Comment: Doesn't the `Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` require an assertion, for example, `cn=test.user`?

Comment: It works without cn= but I'll check it with this, and with the DOMAIN/ tomorrow.

Comment: I tried the following types without dots in the username: cn=testuser,ou=User,dc=test,dc=local - doesn't work, TEST\\testuser - doesn't work, userPrincipalName=testuser@test.local - doesn't work. So i don't know why, but it works now just in case, when I give the "testuser".

Answer (score 1):

The [Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html) must be a valid principal name within the context you are using. (LDAP - AD in your case.)

So a fully qualified DN or userPrincipalName or or domain\samaccountname should work.
We have put up some [JNDI samples](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/JNDI%20Samples)

Comment: I tried the follow types without dots in the username: cn=testuser,ou=User,dc=test,dc=local - doesn't work, TEST\\testuser - doesn't work, userPrincipalName=testuser@test.local - doesn't work. So i don't know why, but it works now just in case, when I give the "testuser".

Comment: "49 52e 1326 ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid." The error code is intresting, too, because the password is correct, when I use the "testuser" SECURITY_PRINCIPAL.

Comment: I checked the winserver security logs, and it seems that the win can't resolve the principal:

env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=testuser,ou=User,dc=test,dc=local");

And the win event log:
Account For Which Logon Failed:
 Security ID:  NULL SID
 Account Name:  cn=test,ou=User,dc=test,dc=local
 Account Domain:  test.local

Failure Information:
 Failure Reason:  An Error occured during Logon.
 Status:   0xc000006d
 Sub Status:  0xc000006d